# How to create breadcrum in a struts2 application

Tags: java, struts2

I am working on struts2 application using Bootstrap template. I want to integrate breadcrumb on each form but i don't want to include static text on each form to include breadcrumb. Is there any way to centralize breadcrumb text and add it dynamically according to actions and methods?

Comment: Add just using normal html and css and change the value based on the page information(ie get the values dynamically)

Comment: Is it possible to check action and methods in customized interceptor add breadcrump value from their?

Comment: Yes you can, only thing you have to do is pass those values to your jsp and manipulate it in breadcrumb

Comment: Can u provide me a short example how can i do this?

Comment: Sure give me some time

Comment: @Can you able to post your interceptor

Answer (score 0):

```
   <ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="#"><%= variable.getValue() %></a></li>
    <li>&gt;</li>
    <li><a href="#"><%= variable.getValue() %></a></li>
    <li>&gt;</li>
    <li><%= variable.getValue() %></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Don't use scriptlets. Since this is struts2 related, use struts2 tags... otherwise use el or jstl... scriptlets are evil.